# 2 months UNIX timestamp

Tags: python, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to retreiving historical daily data from an API that requires the start date and current date, in Epoch Unix timestamp format. The API requires this:

```
data = client.get_historical_data('A-B', '1day', startDate, endDate)
```

The `endDate` has to be now (the moment I run the script) and the `startDate` has to be x-months before the `endDate`.

I am definitely not a pro in Python, the script works but I need help to understand how to declare the `endDate` and `startDate` variables correctly using Epoch Unix timestamp, so that I can retrieve the data of the specific period I need.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use python datetime https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

end = datetime.today()
start = end - relativedelta(months=2)

startDate = int(start.timestamp())
endDate = int(end.timestamp())
```

Look at the *datetime* and *timedelta* objects, are very usefull.

I replaced the use of *timedelta* by *relativedelta* as MrFuppes suggested

Comment: 60 days is not an accurate representation of n months. the OP might be advised to use dateutil's [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to obtain that.

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes, I didn't know relativedelta.

Comment: give it a try and feel free to add it to your answer :)

Comment: despite pip3 install datetime It gives me an error in the library: "No module named 'datetime.relativedelta'; 'datetime' is not a package"

Comment: @li_Marti example fixed, the correct import is `from dateutil import relativedelta`